# Import in Blend for Visual Studio 2013 as vector graphic

Tags: xaml, import, visual-studio-2013, vector-graphics, blend

Importing an Adobe Illustrator file in Blend for Visual Studio 2013 adds a Canvas and images to my project. But if images are added the import is not a vector graphic any more, right?

I hoped I could import that .ai file, resulting in a Path object, so that I have a vector graphic that could be dynamically scaled by window size in my Visual Studio project.

Is there any solution for that?

Comment: Go grab Mike Swanson's [AI to XAML](http://www.mikeswanson.com/xamlexport/) plugin and you can export to XAML from AI directly.

Comment: Unfortunately, this plugin requires an installation of an old version of Illustrator that I not have. Furthermore, I do not create the Adobe Illustrator file by myself; I get a created .ai file. So I do not need and I have not Illustrator.

Comment: Dont pay attention to that, it works just fine on cs5.1 etc. I use it all the time, but yes you would need illustrator.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't used blend so i am not sure about this issue, but as i understand expression design 4 is now free and can open ai files to convert to xaml. Also i think there are svg to xaml converters if u can get the vector file as svg.

Comment: Yes, the tools are free. And I have used it. But as I said, the conversion produces images..